# Android: Calling a function in java from javascript passing variables

Tags: java, javascript, android, variables, var

I'm a bit lost here... I've been looking online and I haven't found anything like what I'm looking for. This is what I'm doing in java

```
ClsAccessor accessors = new ClsAccessor();



class ClsAccessor{
    public String WorkingWithJason(String Json){
        String JsonVar;
        JsonVar ="";
        if (Json != ""){
            generateNoteOnSD("JsonFile.txt", Json);
        }
        JsonVar = getfileFromSDCard("JsonFile.txt");
        return JsonVar;
    }
    public void generateNoteOnSD(String Name, String data){
    //....
    }

    public String getfileFromSDCard(String Name){
    //....
    String data;
    //data = ".....";
    return data;
    }
}


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(accessors, "accessor");
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Main.html");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());


}
```

and moreless this is what I need on javascript

```
var text = "";
function SendData(RecievedTextVariable){
    var text = accessor.WorkingWithJason(RecievedTextVariablejsn);  
    document//accessor.outWorkingWithJason(textjsn);  
    $("#main_div").html("bbbbbb bbbbbbbb"+text);
}
```

Any ideas or any example?

Answer (score 2):

```
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new YourInterface(), "something");

class YourInterface{
    public void out(String value){
        // do something
    }
}
```

Instead of `document.out(text)` use `something.out(text)`.

Comment: can i do a return in the method out and receive it in javascript??

Comment: Wouldn't it be much more fun if you try that by your self? If you have any problems just ask.